# keep getting MemoryError when trying to write a Excel file with cx_Oracle and openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, cx-oracle

i need help with this error, please.

I wrote this script to query an Oracle table and dump all it's content to an excel with .xlsx format. But after several minutes i got an error showing nothing more than MemoryError.

I think that the DB table is big, but not that big that my computer can't handle it, it has approximately 500,000 rows.
I'm using write_only=True method to handle big excel files. 
Here's an extract of my python code:

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

#####OracleConnectionStuff...

curs = orcl.cursor()
sql = "select * from 500KrowsTable"
curs.execute(sql)

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

for row_data in curs:
    ws.append(row_data)

wb.save("tableData.xlsx")
```

And i keep getting MemoryError like so:

```
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xlsxGenerator.py", line X, in <module>
    create_xlsx(tableName, fileName)
  File "xlsxGenerator.py", line X, in create_xlsx
    ws.append(row_data)
  File "DIR\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\write_only.py", line X, in append
    self.writer.send(row)
  File "DIR\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\write_only.py", line X, in _write_header
    cell = WriteOnlyCell(self)
  File "DIR\Python\Python36-32\lib\contextlib.py", line X, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "DIR\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line X, in element
    parent.append(self._top_element)
MemoryError
```